# How to expand nav tabs to take equal widths in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make those two tabs of login and create account equally spaced and centered as given in the picture? I am only able to get them in the left corner and the tabs take up only as long as the text inside (as given in 2nd image). I want to make the tabs look like this:.

[image: first image]

[image: Second image]

Sample Code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#login" id="tab1" class='nav-link active' aria-controls="login" aria-selected='true' role="tab" tabindex=1 data-toggle='tab'>LOGIN</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#create-account" id="tab2" class='nav-link' aria-controls="create-account" aria-selected='false' role="tab" tabindex=0 data-toggle='tab'>CREATE ACCOUNT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1" aria-hidden='false'>
      <!-- Addition of Form 1 -->
      <form class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address <span class='required'>*</span></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password <span class='required'>*</span></label>
          <div class="input-group d-flex flex-row">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <i href='#' class='bi bi-eye-fill ml-2'></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-hover btn-orange rounded-0">SIGN IN</button><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-hover btn-default2 rounded-0">FORGOT YOUR PASSWORD?</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version per the instructions on the `twitter-bootstrap` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#fill-and-justify), use the `nav-fill` class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#login" id="tab1" class='nav-link active' aria-controls="login" aria-selected='true' role="tab" tabindex=1 data-toggle='tab'>LOGIN</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#create-account" id="tab2" class='nav-link' aria-controls="create-account" aria-selected='false' role="tab" tabindex=0 data-toggle='tab'>CREATE ACCOUNT</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1" aria-hidden='false'>
    <!-- Addition of Form 1 -->
    <form class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address <span class='required'>*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password <span class='required'>*</span></label>
        <div class="input-group d-flex flex-row">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <i href='#' class='bi bi-eye-fill ml-2'></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-hover btn-orange rounded-0">SIGN IN</button><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-hover btn-default2 rounded-0">FORGOT YOUR PASSWORD?</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```